# Is it possible to send a signal to a remote machine to halt (breakpoint) when I hit a breakpoint within my own debugger?

Tags: debugging, signals, cluster-computing, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I generally use Eclipse CDT for development.

When I hit a break point, I want to send a signal or some other valid method to another machine on the same network to also break.I have Linux host A (192.168.0.A) running application X in the Eclipse CDT debugger, Linux host B (192.168.0.B) running application Y, and Linux host C (192.168.0.C) running application Z. I have a break point in application X set within the debugger. When I halt at this break point in application X, I want to send something to halt application Y and Z at the same time.

Is this possible? I have some general ideas, but not sure if anything will even work. This generally occurs in cluster computing with the use of MPI, but my systems are not intertwined via MPI.